# WCF, Named Pipes invoke method by url

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I write some plugin application (let's call it "A") who works with other done, external application who share theri api (let's call it "B").

From the plugin (in app B) I can't use advanced libraries so I can't use WCF Client (Autogenerated client or Channel Factory etc.). 
I can only start a new process (i don't want do it) or invoke some url and parse result.

I want achieve the effect as WebService works, something like invoke controller method with pass parameters, for example http :// localhost/Service/Sum?Number1=5&Number2=10.

I don't want use WebService on http because sometimes user will need unlock http port (use netsh). I can write some application who take parameters and I can start it from application B api - but it's unnecessarily complicated.

**It's possible to create WCF client (on named pipes) which methods can be invoke from uri with parameters?**